# Unable to move files to external SD card on SGS2 XXLP2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, external-sd, file-permissions

Running a rooted Galaxy S2 with ICS XXLP2 official leaked rooted build. I have a 32GB microSD card mounted at /sdcard/external_sd in addition to the 16 GB internal storage. I'm unable to copy files to it now, it says write error or permission error.
I use a terminal emulator to create a file

```
touch /sdcard/external_sd/test
```

and this works fine. If I use a file manager ([ES File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop), which supports browsing / on rooted devices), I can't copy files from internal storage to the external SD card. Also, earlier I used the external card as the camera photo storage location, now I can't do so and the camera defaults to internal storage (which is low on space).

If I do an ls -l of both sdcard and external_sd, I see the difference - sdcard has all files listed as belonging to sdcard_r, while external sd lists them as '1023'. 
So is this a leftover UID from a previous ROM install?

I'm scared to do

```
chown -R sdcard_r:system /sdcard/external_sd
```

Is that the way to go about it..or is there any other way to fix permissions?

Comment: So your `ls -l` should also have revealed the permissions, next to the owner. Here the last 6 fields should read `r-wr-w` for an SD-card (at least as long it's formatted using FAT). Is this so? Otherwise, simply adjust that permits everybody to read and write here.